# How to plus to each other numbers from tags

Tags: javascript

I need to plus each number from tags. but can't figureout how to do this, Javascript is new for me.

## html

```
<span class="number">1</span>
<span class="number">2</span>
<span class="number">3</span>
<span class="number">4</span>
```

## javascript

```
var number = document.querySelectorAll('.number');

for ( var i = 0; i < number.length; i++ ) {

    var nums = number[i].textContent;
    var Result = //code to get 1+2+3+4
    console.log(result); // Result must be 10

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, hence the downvotes. Check my answer, that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to solve this problem. Above in your code you are writing code in the loop. which should not be.

You want to add all the items So you can use following code

```
var result=0;
for ( var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++ ) {
        result+= +numbers[i].textContent;
    }
    console.log(result);
```

or

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".number")).reduce((x,y)=>{
    return ((+x.textContent)||x) + +y.textContent
})
```

Code is as follows

```js
var numbers=document.querySelectorAll(".number");
var result=0;

for ( var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++ ) {
    result+= +numbers[i].textContent;
}
console.log(result);
```

```html
<span class="number">1</span>
<span class="number">2</span>
<span class="number">3</span>
<span class="number">4</span>
```

or

```js
var result=[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".number")).reduce((x,y)=>{
    return ((+x.textContent)||x) + +y.textContent
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<span class="number">1</span>
<span class="number">2</span>
<span class="number">3</span>
<span class="number">4</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

for addition convert the string to number as `textContent` will return string and declare result outside the loop to add the values to it on every iteration

```js
var number = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
var result=0;
for ( var i = 0; i < number.length; i++ ) {
    var nums = number[i].textContent;
    result+=Number(nums);
    // Result must be 10

}
console.log(result);
```

```html
<span class="number">1</span>
<span class="number">2</span>
<span class="number">3</span>
<span class="number">4</span>
```

Comment: i need to 1+2+3+4

Comment: that is simple question

Comment: This is the answer.

Comment: *How to plus to each other numbers from tags*. Not at all simple bro.

Comment: I get result but = 1,3,6,10 i need to get just one number 10

Answer (score 0):

The following code will sum up all the number.

```
var number = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
    var result=0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < number.length; i++ ) {
          result+=Number(number[i].textContent);
      }
     console.log(result); // Result must be 10
```

Answer (score 0):

### Simple sum - and Advanced javascript - clean code and naming

I've change the names to more meaningful names, and to use let and const whenever possible.

The first (sum) is yours with simple for.

The second (sum2) use forEach.

The third (sum3) use reduce.

```css
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  console.log('count-', sum, '+', Number(numbers[i].textContent), '=', sum + Number(numbers[i].textContent));
  sum += Number(numbers[i].textContent);
}
console.log('sun', sum);

let sum2 = 0;
[...numbers].forEach(num => sum2 += Number(num.textContent));
console.log('sun2', sum2);

const sum3 = [...numbers].reduce((acc, num) => acc + Number(num.textContent), 0);
console.log('sun3', sum3);
```

```html
<span class="number">1</span>
<span class="number">2</span>
<span class="number">3</span>
<span class="number">4</span>
```

[image]

CodePen (https://codepen.io/omergal/pen/QWWjzBz?editors=1010)